# How to run sudo su with paramiko?

Tags: python, paramiko

I'd like to execute commands by root user. Firstly, I need to execute the command "sudo su" and after executing other commands such as docker pull, git clone, etc in particular session. I want to figure out the most efficient way to do it by using paramiko.

Comment: Why not ssh as the root user?

Comment: I can't log in with root user because there is the configuration of the base AMI in AWS. I launch the instance from the AMI, then connect to the instance and provision it. And after I connect with "centos" I should switch to the root user in order to provision the instance.

Comment: Are you able to configure sudo to add your user rights to execute all commands you need?
Than you might execute each command with sudo as follows: client.exec_command('sudo docker pull')

Answer (score 0):

I realize that it's not ideal, but if you have a chain of commands to execute through sudo you may run them as `sudo bash -c "command1; command2"`:

```
In [11]: stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo bash -c "id; id"')

In [12]: stdout.read().splitlines()
Out[12]:
[b'uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)',
 b'uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)']
```